# ZetaSQL BQ Library not working for mac OS Monterey

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-bigquery

I have a SpringBoot Application that is using Big Query Parser ZetaSQL.
My pom is as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zetasql</groupId>
            <artifactId>zetasql-jni-channel</artifactId>
            <version>2022.08.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

In My Test Class i am trying to extract table names from query.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Querystr = "SELECT * FROM `test.test.test` LIMIT 1000;";
    List<List<String>> tables = Analyzer.extractTableNamesFromStatement(Querystr);

  }
```

However when i try to run the application i get this error:

```
 com.google.zetasql.ClientChannelProvider: Provider com.google.zetasql.JniChannelProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
    at com.google.zetasql.ClientChannelProvider.loadChannel(ClientChannelProvider.java:31)
    at com.google.zetasql.Client.getStub(Client.java:29)
    at com.google.zetasql.LanguageOptions.getDefaultFeatures(LanguageOptions.java:58)
    at com.google.zetasql.LanguageOptions.<init>(LanguageOptions.java:66)
    at com.google.zetasql.AnalyzerOptions.<init>(AnalyzerOptions.java:56)
    at com.google.zetasql.Analyzer.extractTableNamesFromStatement(Analyzer.java:162)
    at com.pexar.sigma.datasources.JdbcDatasourceApplication.main(JdbcDatasourceApplication.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported os.arch
    at com.google.zetasql.JniChannelProvider.getLibraryPath(JniChannelProvider.java:48)
    at com.google.zetasql.JniChannelProvider.<clinit>(JniChannelProvider.java:66)
    ... 14 more
```

I am using macOS Monterey.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have the same problem, M1 Mac running ZetaSQL fails with

Unsupported os.arch
Using the Zulu JDK also didn't solve the problem. Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on an M1 Mac?

I had this issue as there isn't an M1 / ARM build of ZetaSQL.

To fix:

- download an x86 64-bit JVM (I went to https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk and used a different major version to avoid any conflicts)
- set x86 JVM as the Project JVM for IntelliJ (https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version)